# Access Twitter API after firebase simple login

Tags: android, twitter, firebase

So I am using twitter as my authentication mechanism and after a successful login I am able to make calls to access the twitters users information listed here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/twitter.html

```
   String username = (String)authData.getProviderData().get("username");
   String displayName =  (String) authData.getProviderData().get("displayName");
```

Calls like those work perfectly but I want to be able to post tweets as well and I am not sure how to do so after twitter authentication.

There are no real guides in the firebase documents so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not currently possible, because OAuth 1.0a requires requests to be signed with the application secret (which should not be done from the client). You'll need to use a server process (or some other service) to act as the intermediary.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Rob.